# Grouping documents based on a column, then selecting one document from each group that is the max value of another column

Tags: mongodb

I have a table of schedules. I would like to get the entire document for the latest planned schedule for each store. My assumption on the process of selecting such documents are:

- Filter by *DIVISION* and *STORE_ID*
- Group by *DIVISION* and *STORE_ID*
- Select max value of *SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE* for each group
- Return the entire document of each group

However, the multiple attempted aggregate functions I've found online have failed.

This one for example, returns multiple values with the same *DIVISION* and *STORE_ID*. I assume this is because it's grouping by the *SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE*

```
[
    { $match : {DIVISION: divisionId, STORE_ID:{$in :storeIds}} },
    { $sort : { SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE : -1 } },
    { $group: {
        _id : "$_id",
        STORE_ID: {$first:"$STORE_ID"},
        DIVISION: {$first:"$DIVISION"},
        SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE : {$first:"$SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE "},
    }},
]
```

This one doesn't work because the array of documents pushed isn't sorted, so selecting the 0th element isn't the correct one

```
[
    { $match : {DIVISION: divisionId, STORE_ID:{$in :storeIds}} },
    { $sort : { SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE : -1 } },
    { $group: {
        _id : "$_id",
        STORE_ID: {$first:"$STORE_ID"},
        DIVISION: {$first:"$DIVISION"},
        schedules: { $push : "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ["$schedules", 0] } },
]
```

How can I achieve my goal in a single MongoDB query?

#### Data example from my table

```
{
"_id":"abc123",
"DIVISION":"1",
"SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE":"2018-08-03T07:00:00.000Z",
"INSTALL_TYPE":"configInstall",
"STORE_ID":"2",
"VPOS_VERSION":"1.1",
"STATUS":"0"
}
```

Comment: have you tried ? `[
    { $match : {DIVISION: divisionId, STORE_ID:{$in :storeIds}} },
    { $sort : { SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE : -1 } },
    { $group: {
        _id : {STORE_ID: "$STORE_ID", DIVISION:"$DIVISION"},
        SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE : {$first:"$SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE "},
        schedule:{ $first : "$$ROOT" }
    }}
]`

Comment: That worked! But I deleted `SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE : {$first:"$SCHEDULED_INSTALL_DATE "},` and added `{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$schedule"}},` as another action in the pipeline